Is there any way how to delay email sending in Gmail via Google Scripts?
I am looking for a way to change the behavior of clicking the send button in Gmail via Google Script, because I want to delay all emails sent after working hours to next business day.
I have prepared a quick example of what I mean. In appsscript.json I have:
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Prague",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Conditional sending",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_64dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailSend"
      }
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#146b2e",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://developers.google.com/gmail"
    ],
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}

and in script file I have:
function onGmailSend(e) {

  if (condition) {

    // Send email with a delay
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.gmail.message.to, e.gmail.message.subject, e.gmail.message.body, {
      'replyTo': e.gmail.message.from,
      'bcc': e.gmail.bcc,
      'cc': e.gmail.cc,
      'name': e.gmail.name,
      'htmlBody': e.gmail.htmlBody,
      'attachments': e.gmail.attachments,
      'schedule': {
        'sendDate': nextWorkingDayDate
      }
    });
    
    // Prevent the default email sending action
    return false;
  }
  
  // Allow the email to be sent
  return true;
}

I have enabled this script as addon for my gmail account, which I see in gmail account settings under Installed developer add-ons section.
But this does not work and the email is sent immediately anyway.

Could you please explain what you have in the "condition" and also where you return the value (false/true) of the onGmailSend(e) function to prevent the default action of sending emails?

In the condition, I check the current time, and if it is out of business hours, then it is true.  And as for the return value, I thought you just set in appsscript.json an onTriggerFunction that will be automatically called before sending the email and the input parameter will be the message itself - isn't that right?

I'm not sure about this. In any case, I have not seen this either here: AddOns manifest resource or here: Universal actions. Do you know of any reference resource that outlines the expected behavior you describe? I would be grateful if you could share a link to it.
